# Replace array in string from position

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I get trouble on replacing the word into special characters

First, I read the txt file and store each line into $line
and put the special character that I want to change into $table array.

How do I change $line with special character $table array one by one based on the position for example, the txt include three words:

```
pads
password 
qwerty
```

so the program should show

```
p@ds
p@d$
p@ssword
p@$sword
p@$$word
p@$$w0rd
qwerty
```

Now my work just change all special characters into a new word. 
but how to change it using foreach / for loop one by one based on the position
My code as follows

```
 <?php

    $file = fopen("text.txt", "r"); 
    while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);  
    $line = rtrim ($line);    

    $table = array(
        'a'=>'@', 'o'=>'0', 's'=>'$',   
    );


    $length = strlen($line);
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$length ; $i++){ 
        $line = strtr ($line, $table);
        echo $line."<br>";
    };
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job (haven't tested it):

```
$char_array = str_split($line);
$replaced = FALSE;
foreach($char_array as $char) {
    if(array_key_exists($char, $table)) {
        $line = str_replace($char, $table[$char], $line, 1);
        echo $line."<br>";
        $replaced = TRUE;
    }
}
if(!$replaced)
    echo $line."<br>";
```

By setting the *count* argument of [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to 1, you make sure only the current character is replaced and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **strtr()**, use **preg_replace()** like this:

```
    for ($i=0 ; $i<$length ; $i++){ 
          if (array_key_exists($line[$i], $table)) {
             $line = preg_replace('/' . $line[$i] . '/', $table[$line[$i]], $line, 1);
             echo $line."<br>";
          }

    };
```